# Working out the distance between 2 points in one plane only

Tags: algorithm, distance, formula, pythagorean

[image]

How can I find the distance between the two points as shown in the above picture.

I know I can use Pythagoras to find the 'actual' distance between the two points, but I want to find the X distance between them only.

Also, obviously I know I can subtract the x coordinate of point A from that of Point B, but this won't help because they might be the other way around (i.e., B might be on the left and A on the right).

Would be grateful if someone could advise the *simplest* method to discover this distance.

Comment: You need to tell us what you DO know.  Do you know any angles?  Only the x,y coordinates of each point?  What do we know?

Comment: We simply know the X and Y coordinates of each point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the answer already, you subtract the x coordinate from one point to the other.  You simply need to take the absolute value of that and then it doesn't matter which one is greater.

```
absoluteValue(Ax - Bx) = absoluteValue(Bx - Ax)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use absolute value, i.e., abs(a - b)